# How to shuffle list in O(n) in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

It is not hard to shuffle an `array` in O(n), with in place swapping,

How to do it for `list` in OCaml, with O(n)?

---

Requirement:

1. No array or in place usage
2. Consider this as an interview question

Comment: Cheap trick: Copy list to array, shuffle, copy back... should be O(n).

Comment: @phimuemue No, without array or in place of course, consider this as an interview question

Comment: Are there requirements, such as that all possible permutations of the list have to be equally likely?

Comment: I don't think you can do better than `O(n log n)` without mutation.

Comment: @phimuemue of course, which means a "pure" random shuffle

Comment: @sepp2k yes, that's my thought too. But even for O(nlogn), how do you do it?

Comment: O(n log n): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421639/randomly-permute-n-first-elements-of-a-singly-linked-list/4477386#4477386

Comment: Or summed up here: http://phimuemue.com/?p=66

Comment: "Pure" is subjective to the observer; don't use a screwdriver to hammer a nail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lists are immutable, and there's often a *log n* price to pay for working with immutable data. If you're willing to pay this cost, there's an obvious *n log n* approach: tag each list element with a random value, sort based on random value, remove random values. This is the way I shuffle lists in my production code.

Here is the shuffle code from the iOS apps that I sell:

```
let shuffle d =
    let nd = List.map (fun c -> (Random.bits (), c)) d in
    let sond = List.sort compare nd in
    List.map snd sond
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. The interesting thing is that this question popped up to me as I am going to write quicksort. for `quicksort`, I have shuffle the list first, then do the partition, etc. In this case, how do I sort the random values in your code?

Comment: Note that if you shuffle using sorting, not all permutations are equally likely. See this: http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt

Comment: It seems the deviations arise when tags are equal. With 63 bits of tag this is a small deviation. (I read that message from Oleg when it came out. He is awesome.)

Comment: @sepp2k I think the negative point of the attach_value-then-sort algorithm that message was talking about can be easily `fixed by` that `while sorting the attached values, if two values are equal, then generate another 0|1 to decide who comes in front`, i.e., we don't want stable sort. Am I correct? how anyway, that message is correct, if stable sort is used

Comment: Yeah, I always forgot List.map, List.filter, List.fold things. Have to practice more.

Comment: do we need to call `Random.self_init`?

Comment: Yes, if you want a different shuffle each time you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could mimick the riffle shuffle for cards.

A riffle shuffle of a deck of cards means to:

- cut the deck in two parts
- interleave the two parts

It is actually easier to do the reverse permutation:

- have two auxiliary lists A and B, iter through your original list L and push each element randomly (with probability 1/2) in front of A or B.
- L := List.rev A  @  List.rev B  (this can be tail recursive with a custom List.rev).
- repeat k times.

According to "Mathematical developments from the analysis of riffle shuffling, by Persi Diaconis, 2002", choose k = 3/2 log_2(n) + c. Indeed, the total variation distance between uniformity and the result falls exponentially fast to 0: it is approximately halved each time you increment c. You could choose c=10.

Space O(1) (if you destroy L), time O(n log n). But there are O(n log n) calls to the random generator, while Jeffrey Scofield's solution only needs O(n) random bits, but Θ(n) space.

Comment: List.rev_append is tail recursive