# Generate a random permutation of the elements of a list OCaml

Tags: list, random, ocaml, element

i whant generate a random permutation of elements of a list,
Example:

```
listString =  ["a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"]
```

i whant something like:

```
result = ["a"; "e"; "f"; "b"; "d"; "c"]
```

but that result change in each call of the function.
So when i call the function in second time return something like:

```
result = ["c"; "d"; "b"; "f"; "e"; "a"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to shuffle list in O(n) in OCaml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095541/how-to-shuffle-list-in-on-in-ocaml)

Comment: thats i seeing, but that function repeat the same permutation in every call of that function. I try generate a random int 'n' and use that function shuffle n times.

Comment: Now Random.int do the same number every times :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution:

```
 let shuffle d = begin
    Random.self_init ();
    let nd = List.map (fun c -> (Random.bits (), c)) d in
    let sond = List.sort compare nd in
    List.map snd sond
 end
```

the line Random.self_init (); Initialize the generator with a random seed chosen in a system-dependent way.

Comment: You probably want to initialize the RNG only once, at the start of your program (and outside of the shuffle function).